# How do I set an PostgreSQL RLS update policy for a one-to-many relation?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I'm just getting my feet wet with [PostgreSQL RLS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) and I'm pretty confused. I have the following tables:

```
users
| id|role          |email            |
|--:|:-------------|:----------------|
|  1|authenticated | bob@gmail.com   |
|  2|authenticated | alice@gmail.com |
|  3|authenticated | jane@gmail.com  |
|  4|authenticated | mark@gmail.com  |

profiles
| id|name  | company_id|
|--:|:-----|----------:|
|  1|Bob   |          1|
|  2|Alice |          1|
|  3|Jane  |          2|
|  4|Mark  |         NA|

companies
| id|name |
|--:|:----|
|  1|ABC  |
|  2|DEF  |
```

Note that I am using [Supabase](https://supabase.com/), which sets up the users table and roles automatically.

I am trying to set an update policy for the companies table. Supabase has a starter template which looks like this

```sql
CREATE POLICY "companies"
ON public.companies
FOR UPDATE USING (
  auth.email() = email
) WITH CHECK (
  auth.email() = email
);
```

Can someone ELI5? What is `auth` in this context? How can I adapt this to fit my schema?

Comment: What is "ELI5"?

Comment: "*What is `auth` in this context?*" - it's the schema in which the `email()` function is living. Probably provided by supabase if you don't know about it.

Comment: "*I am trying to set an update policy for the companies table*" - how would you like your policy to work?

Comment: @Bergi thanks! Anyone associated with a company should be able to update that company. In my example, Bob and Alice can update company 1. Jane can update company 2.

Comment: ELI5 = Explain It Like I'm 5 (In other words, please don't assume I have much background knowledge about Row Level Security ...because I don't ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to unpack here.

### What's `auth` in this context?

Auth is the schema where Supabase deploys the auth-related tables and helper functions.

### What does the function `auth.email()` do?

If you use PSQL, then you can check the definition of these helper functions:

`\df+ auth.email`

```
select     
coalesce(     
nullif(current_setting('request.jwt.claim.email', true), ''),
(nullif(current_setting('request.jwt.claims', true), '')::jsonb ->> 'email')
)::text
```

So, this is a function to check the user's email is the same as the authenticated user's. This is to ensure that the user is trying to update their own row. Please note that this function is [deprecated](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#deprecated-features).
The current recommendation is to use `auth.jwt() ->> 'email'` instead.

These are the helper functions listed in the auth schema:

- `auth.email()`
- `auth.jwt()`
- `auth.role()`
- `auth.uid()`

### Exploring further:

The [documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/learn/auth-deep-dive/auth-policies) also hints at a more complex scenario where only users with a defined email ending can update something:

```
create policy "Only Blizzard staff can update leaderboard"
  on my_scores
  for update using (
    right(auth.jwt() ->> 'email', 13) = '@blizzard.com'
  );
```

Suppose you want to cover more broad and complex cases when creating Row Level Security policies. In that case, I do recommend using [custom claims](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-custom-claims) as it provides more flexibility to create more scenarios and different roles for your platform.

### Using custom claims to create a company update policy:

Install custom claims by running the [SQL script](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-custom-claims/blob/main/install.sql) in the [SQL Editor](https://app.supabase.com/project/_/sql):

Set the claim for the user:

```
select set_claim('00000-0000-45c1-8dfb-6eeb7cf0b92e', 'company', '1');
```

Then, you can use it on RLS policies:

```
CREATE POLICY "User can update team details if they belong to the company."
ON public.companies
FOR UPDATE USING (
  get_my_claim('company') = id
);
```

Another way to achieve this is [using joins](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#policies-with-joins) in your RLS, but that will be less performant as you are using a join query to check every update.

Comment: +1 this is very well written and helpful. But it's still not clear to me how to write the specific policy I'm after.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Ben. It wasn't clear what your goal was until I read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75072626/how-do-i-set-an-postgresql-rls-update-policy-for-a-one-to-many-relation/75073798#comment132483291_75072626). I've added two examples that you can use to achieve this.