# Row level security issues on insert

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security

I am trying to create an `RLS` in `supabase` for an `initiative_categories` table since when the service creates a new initiative it calls another function to create a new record in the `initiative_categories` tables but when it does the operation Insertion into the table returns a 403 with the following error: `new row violates row-level security policy for table "initiative_categories"`.

Currently my row security level has been configured like this:

```
(initiative_id = ( SELECT initiatives.id
 FROM initiatives
 WHERE ((initiatives.id = initiative_categories.initiative_id) AND (uid() = initiatives.user_id))
 LIMIT 1)
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to recreate these policies using [custom claims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75073798/2188186])? 

It is usually a lot easier to debug once you set it up.

Comment: No never tried before

Comment: Please post the table definitions of the involved tables, the full definitions of the rls policies on them, the code of the function that is called, and the code that is calling it. We won't be able to help you without those details.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```sql
(exists (SELECT initiatives.id
 FROM initiatives
 WHERE id = initiative_id AND uid() = user_id)
)
```

Comment: Hi, no it did not work, but thanks!. I end up doing a validation between ids in front before the request is made `userId === initiative.user_id`